# Curl on Fedora does not accept Cloudflare https

Tags: centos, https, fedora, openssl, curl

Using curl on a clean vanilla Fedora 21 to retrieve a site hosted via the cloudflare https service gives an error:

```
curl https://www.opencpu.org
>> curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
```

Also:

```
curl https://www.cloudflare.org
>> curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.
```

This problem only appears on Fedora, not on Ubuntu or Mac running the same version of curl. I suppose it must be related to nns then:

```
curl --version
>> curl 7.37.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.37.0 NSS/3.17.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3

certutil -L
>> certutil: function failed: SEC_ERROR_LEGACY_DATABASE: The certificate/key database is in an old, unsupported format.
```

Any guess to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does `wget` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora bug is at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1185708

Cause is curl using NSS, and not wanting to diverge from other NSS using programs.

Currently not fixed as of Jul 2015 in Fedora 22

Answer (score 2):

The common factor with both of these sites is that they use ECC SSL certificates to secure their https connections, rather than the traditional RSA certificates used by most sites. These are currently very rare, but they are expected to increase in popularity in the future.

Both the versions of curl and NSS in use were built with ECC and therefore ought to support these certificates, so I think you've run into a bug in Fedora and should report it. A [related bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1058776) was recently fixed in RHEL 7.

As a workaround, you can use `wget` instead of `curl`, which has no problem connecting to these sites (though the latter returns a 409 Conflict error).

Answer (score -2):

Please try

`bash
yum update nss`

Comment: This answer isn't very useful without explaining the reasoning behind the commands. I'd recommend that you [edit] it to improve it.